# bind changes to json with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm wondering if you can bind changes on your json with jquery by using change() just like agularjs scope and models?

Here is my code:

```
var data = ['data1', 'data2']; // initiate object data.
$(data).change(function() { 
  console.log('do something');
});
```

and when I add an element on json.

```
 data.push('test4');
```

and expecting to print something like

```
do something
```

on my console.

Comment: Your problem doesn't seem to have anything to do with JSON. JSON is a **language-independent**, textual data-exchange format. What you have is a JavaScript array.

Comment: assuming my var data is composed of json objects.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). You probably mean you have an array of objects. It still doesn't have nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: But to answer your question, no, jQuery doesn't support something like this.

Comment: okay thanks! any other way to do something like this? or do I need to call a function that updates this over and over again?

Comment: jQuery doesn't support this. Nor does JavaScript in most browsers. It will be possible in the future with [observe()](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es7/observe/)

Comment: Array.observe in this case

Comment: there are pub/sub libraries you can use

Comment: You could use getter/setter for a property on an object that would then trigger an event for you.  But, it will restrict which browser versions are supported.

Comment: @ChrisCaviness I don't get it, could you please give me a link or example on how to do that? sorry I'm still learning. :)

thanks for all your quick response, truly appreciated.

Comment: Sure, try this one https://www.google.com/webhp?q=javascript+getter+setter#q=javascript+getter+setter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for this type of problem **Observable Arrays** may be help you.
try out this **[link](https://github.com/mennovanslooten/Observable-Arrays)** from github

Answer (score 3):

You could use [**Delegation Pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) to achieve this.

Create a custom class that wraps an `Array instance`.Delegate methods of `Array` and trigger your events.

Here's an small demonstration-

```
function CustomeArray() {//A warpper function
    this.arr = [];
    this.arr.push.apply(this.arr, arguments);
    this.callbacks = [];
    this.event = {
        "operation": "none"
    };
    return this;
}
//A getter method to get underlying array 
CustomeArray.prototype.get = function () {
    return this.arr;
}
//A methood to add callbacks
CustomeArray.prototype.change = function (callback) {
    if (!(callback in this.callbacks)) {
        this.callbacks.push(callback);
    }
    return this;
};
//A method to trigger callbacks 
CustomeArray.prototype.triggerChange = function (changes) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.callbacks.length; i++) {
        this.callbacks[i].call(this, this.event, changes);
    }
}
//Delegating push method
CustomeArray.prototype.push = function (element) {
    this.arr.push.call(this.arr, element);
    this.event.operation = "push";
    this.triggerChange(element);
    return this;
};

/** Other method delegation code
**
** eg slice(),concat() etc
**
**/

//Using custome array
var custome = new CustomeArray(1, 2, 3);
custome.change(function (event, element) {
    alert(element + " is " + event.operation + "ed")
})
custome.push(100);
console.log(custome.get())
```

### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/1rqsdgab/)

Hope this help :)